# Calling an overloaded operator from a pointer

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a simple C++ test class, that has a `char * operator()` working fine.
The thing is, when I'm creating it on the heap, I can't use it.

```
test t;
printf(t);
```

is ok, but

```
test *t=new test();
printf(t);
```

isn't. Is there any way around it beside printf(*t)?

Comment: Please, please, please, please, if you want to use `printf` do it only with constants and not with arbitrary strings. (I will also mention `std::string` and `std::cout` in passing)

Comment: ... for example `printf("%s", t)`, if you want to stick to `printf`.

Comment: Why it doesn't work: Type `test*` doesn't have an `operator char*`. It in fact has no methods or members. It's a pointer, and that is a built-in non-class type.

Answer (score 5):

An implicit conversion to `char*` may sound like a good idea, but trust me, it isn't. Guess why `std::string` doesn't have one. Just write a `c_str` method and call `printf("%s", t->c_str())`. Or even better, overload `operator<<` for your class. If you show us the class, we can help you.

Comment: You could mention with few words why it is a bad idea.

Comment: I know, it was just a test case.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you really need to convert *a pointer* (which has to be correctly initialized, by the way...) to a `char*`, this isn't possible.

You can only implement operators for *values* (or references) of your class within the class. Some operators can be defined outside of the class, but casting operators aren't (for example, `operator+` can be implemented outside, taking two parameters).

Given the fact that arithmetic operators can be implemented outside of classes (`operator<<` is an arithmetic operator), you can implement a stream operator for output to, for example, `std::cout`, **even with pointers**.

```
std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream & o, const test & t) {
    return o << t.toString();  // use std::string here, not c-strings!
}
std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream & o, const test * t) {
    return o << t->toString(); // use std::string here, not c-strings!
}
```

**See live**: http://ideone.com/BZfcji

Answer (score 0):

You need to *allocate* memory to `test *t` before you can use it, else your pointer doesn't point to any memory.

You do it like so:

```
test * t= new test();
```

you'll also have to release it again when you're done:

```
delete t;
```

Also what of `*t` are you trying to print with `printf`?  The address it points to, or some content of it's members?  If the latter, you should overload an appropriate operator to do so.

Another thing, don't use `printf` in C++. Use `std::cout` and overload `operator<<` on your `test` class.

Comment: What he is trying to print is `t->operator char*()`. That's not the appropriate operator, of course, but it is what he intended.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your heap object as a *reference*, instead of as a pointer.

```
test *my_heap_object = new test();
test &t = *my_heap_object;
// now you can use 't', as if it was local,
// instead of dereferencing the pointer each time.
printf(t);
t.do_something();
t++;
```

Some more explanation can be found on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C++%29).

Comment: @FredOverflow, I do not see why, if the heap object is properly managed. It helps hide implementation details from subsequent method calls, for example. Of course, one would check for a null-pointer first. Could you please elaborate why you think this is a bad thing? I am very curious.